# Redirect on backslash domain to make the link shorter dont work

Tags: html, .htaccess

Im trying to redirect a backslash domain example `https://mrepix.dk/d` to `https://mrepix.dk/projects/discord` to make the link shorter but when I try it redirects to `https://mrepix.dk/projects/discord/d` please help me to remove the d from the link my code is

````
Redirect 301 / https://mrepix.dk/projects/discord/```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
  Redirect 301 /d/ https://mrepix.dk/projects/discord/
```

Your original code was using `/` in the pattern . Since you want to redirect a specific directory ,  I changed your `/`  to `/d` .

Make sure to clear your browser cached data before testing this.